# Commands for reading, loading and unloading drivers on BeagleBone Black?

Tags: beagleboneblack

I am using a BeagleBone Black with Xenomai and RTnet on top. As some real-time programs are not working it could be that the installed drivers on my BeagleBone Black are still the standard drivers and not the real-time drivers.

As I did not find anything on internet (only how to install drivers for Windows when using BeagleBone Black) I would like to ask you if anybody knows a command for BeagleBone Black to read, load and unload installed drivers on BBB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the commands for read, load and unload driver/modules. See the following output of the command window: the commands are lsmod for reading, insmod for loading and rmmod for unloading.

```
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by    Tainted: G
rtipv4                 18699  0
rtpacket                4179  0
rt_ticpsw              26115  0
rt_davinci_mdio         4570  0
rt_smsc                 2165  0
rtnet                  28479  3 rtipv4,rtpacket,rt_ticpsw
omap_rng                4174  0
# insmod
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2019-03-16 12:39:06 CET) multi-call binary.

Usage: insmod FILE [SYMBOL=VALUE]...

Load the specified kernel modules into the kernel

# rmmod
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2019-03-16 12:39:06 CET) multi-call binary.

Usage: rmmod [-wfa] [MODULE]...

Unload kernel modules

        -w      Wait until the module is no longer used
        -f      Force unload
        -a      Remove all unused modules (recursively)

#
```